# Disable CSS style for particular page fragment

Tags: css, iframe

I was searching and found some posts which are similar but none of them answered to my "special" question.

What I have is a page with header and footer styled statically. In the middle (the content) can be some HTML+CSS from the users.

What I don't want is that they define some CSS rules which would mess up the header, footer or the whole body.

Using an iframe is not really a solution.

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do with this? You could provide *some* properties, but not all. Or maybe use a GUI interface to tweak the CSS?

Answer (score 3):

The [YUI3 CSS Reset](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/cssreset/) code can work contextually.

Just include the code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.3.0/build/cssreset/reset-context-min.css">
```

And add your CSS *after* the user's CSS, so that yours is evaluated last. Then, reset the CSS on your elements by giving them a class attribute like this:

```
class="yui3-cssreset"
```

Just make sure that your declarations are as specific as possible, and that they are all `!important`.

But why are you allowing the user to supply their own CSS? You *do* know that IE can interpret JavaScript from a CSS file with some black magic CSS properties?

It's not safe to do this.

Comment: Couldn't the user specified styles simply use a selector with a larger weight then the ones applied by yui3? Also, couldn't they use the !important flag to override those values outright?

Comment: Filter it out before rendering it. I'm not really liking the idea of allowing users to have their own CSS. At least let them do it in an `<iframe>`.

Comment: Yes, you still would have to sanitize their CSS. You might want to include that in your answer. But I'm glad we both agree that this is still, all around, not a good idea :)

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution involving sanitizing their input is to give all of your style attribute's the !important flag - then search and replace out any !important flags that the user may have entered in their custom CSS.

Here is some more info about that flag: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/02/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/

A simpler solution is to remove all  tags from the user input - and only allow CSS to be applied to the style attribute of a particular element.

Either of these solutions are far from bullet proof, however. A user could simply create an absolutely positioned element to cover up any parts of the website that they wish to. If you want to stop this, you will have no choice but to intelligently parse each style attribute that they specify and remove ones that could potentially harm the website layout. This is a very delicate operation - and assuming you can do this correctly, any attribute you disalow will diminish the usefulness of letting them write their own styles in the first place.

I think you have to ask yourself: do you really trust these users to write their own CSS and HTML? Or might it be a better option to investigate [textile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Textile_%28markup_language%29) or markdown*? If you do trust these users, then shouldn't this be a non-issue? I guess more information about the nature of this content would help me give you more appropriate solutions.

*I can't post a direct link to the homepage due to StackOverflow spam preventative measures. The first link of a google search of "markdown" is where you can learn more. Sorry.